# Make other nodes follow when dragging a node in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm new to cytoscape.js, I just want to make other nodes follow when dragging one node.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Write a listener, and update the other node positions appropriately in your callback:

- [eles.on()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.on)
- [node.position()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  I just want to make other nodes to follow automatically  when dragging one node.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Note you have to save off the original positions at the grab event, and then update during the drag event.

```
function add_drag_listeners()
{
    var all = cy.elements("node");
    for (j = 0; j < all.length; j++)
    {
        cynode = all[j];
        cynode.on("grab",handle_grab);
        cynode.on("drag",handle_drag);
    }
}
var grab_x = 0;
var grab_y = 0;
var drag_subgraph = [];
function handle_grab(evt)
{
    grab_x = this.position().x ;
    grab_y = this.position().y ;
    var succ = this.successors();
    drag_subgraph = [];
    var succstr = "";
    for (i = 0; i < succ.length; i++)
    {
        if (succ[i].isNode())
        {
            var old_x = succ[i].position().x;
            var old_y = succ[i].position().y;
            succstr += " " + succ[i].data("id");
            drag_subgraph.push({old_x:old_x, old_y:old_y, obj:succ[i]});
        }
    }
}
function handle_drag(evt)
{
    var new_x = this.position().x;
    var new_y = this.position().y;
    var delta_x = new_x - grab_x;
    var delta_y = new_y - grab_y;
    for (i = 0; i < drag_subgraph.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = drag_subgraph[i].obj;
        var old_x = drag_subgraph[i].old_x;
        var old_y = drag_subgraph[i].old_y;
        var new_x = old_x + delta_x;
        var new_y = old_y + delta_y;
        obj.position({x:new_x, y:new_y});
    }
}
```